# how to move array from javascript to php and print it

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

how can i pass an array from java script to php and print the first value ?

this is my code :

here is the javascript code :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>  </title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'>     </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
<style type='text/css'>
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(function(){
var values = new Array();

$(".submit").on("click", function () {
values.push($('input[name="fname"]').val());
});

$(".show-button").on("click", function () {
$("#demo").html(values.join("<br>"));
});
});//]]> 

</script>
```

Html Code :

```
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" method="GET">Type the words here:
<input type="text" name="fname">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" class="submit">
<input type="submit" value="show">
</form>
<input type="button" class="show-button" value="Print ">
<p id="demo"></p>
```

php code :

```
<?php
echo @$_GET['values[0]']; 
?>
</body>

</html>
```

when i click submit it works well with javascript , also when i click print
but when it comes to php , nothing happened with "show" submit !!
any help please?

Comment: You need to use AJAX, php is server side and JS is client side.

Comment: echo @$_GET['fname'];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to send the values as a string (this is required due to the underlying protocol), you need to *encode* them. One of the standard ways to do this is to use JSON. So at the client side:

```
var array = ['some', 'array'];
// send it to the client via XHR
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/path/to/backend/reciever.php');
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('data', JSON.stringify(array)); // stringify as JSON
xhr.send(fd); // send the complete data
xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
};
```

Then on the backend:

```
$recieved = $_POST['data']; // get recieved json encoded data
$decoded = json_decode($recieved); // decode it back to an array
echo $decoded[0]; // echo the first element
```

What we are doing above is basically encoding the data as JSON and then sending it to the backend. Then decoding it back on backend and echoing out what we need.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can include the function below in your **javascript**:

```
function sendToPHP(myValues) {
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   data: html,
   url: "?data="+myValues,
   success: function(msg){
     alert(msg);
   }
});
}
```

and pass the values to `sendToPHP(values)` accordingly where you need to.

And your **PHP** part will be:

```
if (isset($_GET['data']))
    echo $_GET['data'];
```